# Stylesheet violation pressable error: "pointerEvents" is not a valid style property

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I need to solve this error:

```
Invariant Violation: "pointerEvents" is not a valid style property.
StyleSheet pressable: {
  "flex": 1,
  "pointerEvents": "auto"
}
```

There is no pressable, pointerEvents if I try to find it globally. There is none of it in any file.

Another error is :

```
Error: Requiring module "node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/src/views/modern/Drawer.tsx",
which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: "pointerEvents" is not a valid style property.
```

Things I've done :

1.Reinstall Mac, start from factory setting

2.Reinstall simulator

3.Creating new react-native app which is fine and shows no error like this

4.It shows stylesheet pressable , but there is no "pressable" style on stylesheet , there are `<pressable></pressable>` and I changed it to `<button>`, nothing changes it still shows the same error

5.Recreating the error with creating :

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
       pressable : {
         pointerEvents:'NONNEEEE'
       }
    })
```

it does create the same error. But still can't find any pointerEvents class / style / components

6. Reinstalling React navigation, drawer nothing changes

Here the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with pointer events but [this](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2022/12/13/pointer-events-in-react-native) suggest that you have to do some additional configuration

Comment: @phantomSpooks got it trying it out now , going to configure Xcode project’s info.plist.

Comment: That error seems to provide you a list of valid style props. Have you reviewed the list of the valid style props?

Comment: @DrewReese yes I know I wish it is that simple since even if I search for "pressable" or "pointerEvents" in any style there is none of it, thank you for editing the question tho

Comment: your question lack of informations, like what package and version you using, where is the code giving error?

Comment: It only says that drawer giving error navigation drawer that has style pointerEvents, but there is no pointerEvents in style or prop

Comment: In react-native, pointerEvents is a prop, not a style.<View pointerEvents="none" /> this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912834/what-is-pointer-event-in-react-native

Comment: The pointerEvents which gives the error is in this class "drawer/src/views/modern/Overlay.tsx", for a workaround try with comment the line in class. I checked in page https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/drawer/src/views/modern/Overlay.tsx

Comment: @react-navigation/drawer published new patch 9 days ago. I think this patch has a bug, so lowering your @react-navigation/drawer version to 6.5.6 might solve your problem.

Comment: "There is no pressable, pointerEvents if I try to find it globally please please stop suggesting there is any pressable or pointerEvent, there is none of it in any file" please stop suggesting this, if this is so simple I already find it , and I already point it out at point 5

Comment: Please don't post [the same question multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75154963/drawer-pressable-error-invariant-violation-pointerevents-is-not-a-valid-sty). Instead, update your original question to clarify how it's not a duplicate, if indeed it isn't; or ask how to understand the instructions in the duplicate, if that's what you are having problems with.

Comment: "Help me or I will lose my job" is one of the most obnoxious and manipulative phrases to place in front of volunteer helpers. Keep your writing succinct and free of begging please.

Answer (score 3):

For me lowering `@react-navigation/drawer` version to v6.5.0  fixed my problem.

I've been struggling with same error for hours. Contributers released new patch few days ago `@react-navigation/drawer` v6.5.7. But I haven't found any patch note about changing `Drawer.tsx` file.

Also you can double check your navigation components. Maybe one of your components returned `null` or doesn't have `default export`.

Comment: this might be the answer , what command do you use to lower drawer version ? i can't find source of info to lower it anywhere

Comment: @JzxNaga just install exact version with ```yarn``` or ```npm```.  ```npm i @react-navigation/drawer@6.5.0``` or ```yarn add @react-navigation/drawer@6.5.0```

Comment: Thx, Lowering "@react-navigation/drawer" from "^6.6.2" to "6.5.0" solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Use pointerEvents property on the tag element instead of CSS stylesheet

```
  <View style={styles.pressable} pointerEvents={'none'}> 
    your content
  </View>
```

Comment: there is no styles.pressable

Comment: there is no pointerEvents if you find it globally

Comment: style={styles.pressable} im not even using this anywehere there is no styles.pressable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To not stay block, I open the file and commented the line with pointerEvents.